# Timeout issue - SQL Server Native Client 10.0, TCP Provider - Error 258

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

Apology if this is already answered somewhere.

I have a very complex stored procedure which takes date range as parameters and perform some actions. The problem is it is timing out when I provide longer range of dates. It is totally working fine with those ranges from SQL Server Management Studio.

Environment:

```
Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008, PHP, IIS, 
SQL Server Driver (php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6)
```

Error I am getting:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].
```

How can I increase Time of execution for this procedure or overall for the application?

Answer (score 3):

We spent 5 days looking for the solution for this problem, and it was just to close the connections.

The timeout just happened when we opened two connections, one after another and didn't close them.